# Replacing column names, with matching column names, that have a label attached

Tags: r, label, match, hmisc

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(haven)
library(Hmisc)
library(foreign)

df <- fread("A B D C E
               1 2 2 3 1")
```

For some of the variables I want to add column labels `Lbs` (mainly for Stata use).

```
Lbl <- structure(list(Varcode = structure(1:3, class = "factor", levels = c("A", 
"B", "C")), Variables = c("Variable label for variable A", "Variable label for variable B", 
"Variable label for variable C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Since not all variables have labels, I want to replace the column names in `df`, that match the column names in `Lbl`, with the column names in `Lbl`, that have labels attached.

The following code only works if all variables have labels and they are in order:

```
# set labels
for (i in seq_len(nrow(Lbl))) {
  Hmisc::label(df[[Lbl$Varcode[i]]]) <- Lbl$Variables[i]
}
```

[image]

How should I add the labels to the correct columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each variable in your `df`, get the corresponding label in `Lbl`. If the latter doesn't exist, then move to the next variable.

```r
library(data.table)
library(haven)
library(Hmisc)
library(foreign)

df <- fread("A B D C E
             1 2 2 3 1")

Lbl <- structure(list(Varcode = structure(1:3, class = "factor", levels = c("A", 
                                                                            "B", "C")), Variables = c("Variable label for variable A", "Variable label for variable B", 
                                                                                                      "Variable label for variable C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")



for (i in names(df)) {
  label <- Lbl[Lbl$Varcode == i, 2]
  if (length(label) == 0) next
 
  Hmisc::label(df[[i]]) <- label
}

df
#>             A          B     D          C     E
#>    <labelled> <labelled> <int> <labelled> <int>
#> 1:          1          2     2          3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]